# ID of edited element + make plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, edit

I have some DIVs and script, that can edit text in this DIVs. On click - the script replace DIV with the TEXTAREA and user can edit the TEXT. On blur - the script have to remove the TEXTAREA and insert edited text into DIV.
1. But the script replace all DIVs in page, not only the one edited...
2. I want to make plugin from this script. To edit other elements, like H1, H2. etc...

http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/4a44G/1/

HTML

```
<div>Please click me DIV 1!!</div>
<div>Please click me DIV 2!!</div>
<div>Please click me DIV 3!!</div>
<h1>Please click me H1 1!!</h1 >
<h1>Please click me H1 2!!</h1 >
<h1>Please click me H1 3!!</h1 >
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {     

   $("div").click(function() {
       if ($(this).children('input').length === 0) {
            var inputbox = "<input type='text' class='inputbox' value=\""+$(this).text()+"\">";
          $(this).html(inputbox);
          $("input.inputbox").focus();         
          $("input.inputbox").blur(function() {
             var value = $(this).val();
             $("div").text(value);
        });
      }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("div").click(function() {
    if ($(this).children('input').length === 0) {
            var nID=$(this);
        var inputbox = "<input type='text' class='inputbox' value=\""+$(this).text()+"\">";
        $(this).html(inputbox);
        $("input.inputbox").focus();         
        $("input.inputbox").blur(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(nID).text(value);
        });
    }
});


 $("h1").click(function() {
    if ($(this).children('input').length === 0) {
            var nID=$(this);
        var inputbox = "<input type='text' class='inputbox' value=\""+$(this).text()+"\">";
        $(this).html(inputbox);
        $("input.inputbox").focus();         
        $("input.inputbox").blur(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(nID).text(value);
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4a44G/13/

```
$("div").text(value);
```

selects all elements of type `div`, but you have to select the textboxes parent div, so you have to write:

```
$("input.inputbox").blur(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().text(value);
});
```

If the markup can change, you can also write:

```
$(this).closest('div').text(value);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4a44G/9/

Comment: thank you, for solution... is it possible make plugin from this script ?